# Interface Orientation iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I would like to know if i can change the interface orientation in iOS. I changed the return type to YES in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return YES;
}
```

But nothing has changed when i started the simulator. 
What's going on? Could someone help me?

Comment: i'm using a TabBarController...

Comment: do you rotated the simulator to all possible directions ?

Comment: yes! and i also include them on .plist properties...

Comment: what happened when you rotated the simulator ?

Comment: i didn't see any behavior of the simulator. i changed the orientation and nothing happened!

Comment: what version of SDK are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually change the orientation by following method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) animated:(BOOL)]
```

Comment: put this code in viewDidLoad if you want initially change the orientation or put in any event of control

Comment: You can put this line in the viewDidLoad method of yur view controller

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open your projectName-info.plist and add the orientations you want (under the "Supported interface orientations" -> Add new item)

EDIT: A UITabBarController will only autorotate if all of its view controllers are set to autorotate.

Comment: well, i think that the problem is bigger than i thought... i have a tab bar controller, and the "son" is a table view controller... and the table view controller "controls" three cells...